# How to get only different words from two pandas.DataFrame columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame with columns id, keywords1 and keywords2. I would like to get only words from column keywords2 that are not in the column keywords1. Also I need to clean my new column with different words from meaningless words like phph, wfgh... I'm only interested in English words.

Example:

```
data = [[1, 'detergent', 'detergent for cleaning stains'], [2, 'battery charger', 'wwfgh, old, glass'], [3, 'sunglasses, black, metal', 'glass gggg jik xxx,'], [4, 'chemicals, flammable', 'chemicals, phph']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'keywords1','keywords2']) 

df
```

Comment: For the first part you can con`cat`enate all the rows of `keyword2`, `split` the concatenated version to get all the words, convert the list of words to a `set`, and get the `.difference` from the words in column `keyword1`. Something along the lines of 
`set(df.keywords1.str.cat().split()).difference(df.keywords2.str.cat().split())`.
For the cleaning part, you can look into using stop words.

Comment: I already used stopwords but text like phph or wfgh will still stay in the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

#we split to get words - by every sequence of 1, or more non-letters characters

df["keywords1"]=df["keywords1"].str.split("[^\w+]").map(set)

df["keywords2"]=df["keywords2"].str.split("[^\w+]").map(set)

df["keywords3"]=np.bitwise_and(np.bitwise_xor(df["keywords1"], df["keywords2"]), df["keywords2"])
#optional-if you wish to keep it as a string, and not set:
df["keywords3"]=df["keywords3"].str.join(", ")
```

Outputs:

```py
   id  ...              keywords3
0   1  ...  cleaning, for, stains
1   2  ...    , wwfgh, glass, old
2   3  ...  jik, xxx, glass, gggg
3   4  ...                   phph
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
def words_diff(words1, words2) 
    kw1=words1.str.split() 
    kw2= words2.str.split() 
    diff=[x for x in kw2 if x not in kw1]
    return diff


df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: words_diff(x['keywords1'] , x['keywords2'] ), axis=1)
```

Comment: when I'm trying to run this: df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: words_diff(x['keyword1'] , x['keyword2'] ), axis=1)  I'm getting KeyError: ('keyword1', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: 'keyword1' and 'keyword2' should be the exact name of your df columns. I think I did mistake in your case it should be keywords1 and keywords2

Comment: def words_diff(words1, words2):
    kw1=words1.split(" ") 
    kw2= words2.split(" ") 
    diff=[x for x in keyword2 if x not in keyword1]
    return diff 

df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: words_diff(x['keyword1'] , x['keyword2'] ), axis=1)

I'm still getting KeyError: ('keyword1', 'occurred at index 0')